# Three.js materials not being applied using .obj and .mtl files

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I downloaded a free 3d model and am trying to view it with three.js. The model is loading in fine but the materials aren't loading properly. The only ones that load are the wine bottles behind the bar, nothing else has any texture applied.

[Example site showing problem here](http://swiftdigital.ltd.uk/threejs/)

This is how I am loading in the model:

```
// load in the bar 3d model
var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
mtlLoader.load( 'bar1/3d-model.mtl', function ( materials ) {

    materials.preload();

    var objLoader2 = new THREE.OBJLoader2();
    objLoader2.setMaterials( materials.materials );
    objLoader2.load( 'bar1/3d-model.obj', function ( event ) {

    scene.add( event.detail.loaderRootNode );

    }, function() {
        // success
    }, function() {
        // error
    });
});
```

Comment: Your .mtl file does not contain any reference to texture files, I think you might want to look at the source: where are you exporting this from, and how? (unless you used "texture" to mean "procedural material definition with certain specifics"... which is a lot harder to get similar looking from source to realtime renderer).

Comment: Ah ok. I downloaded it from here: https://www.cgtrader.com/free-3d-models/interior/office/wine-bar and used the obj and MTL zips. I just assumed it would come out rendered like it is in the image. Do I have to link textures to the materials myself or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [the MTL file](http://swiftdigital.ltd.uk/threejs/bar1/3d-model.mtl) used by your OBJ file, you will notice it doesn't have any reference to texture maps. Texture maps are usually referenced with lines like:

```
map_Ka image.jpg
map_Kd image.jpg
map_Ks image.jpg    
map_Nd image.jpg
map_d image.jpg
map_bump image.jpg
```

If your model doesn't include them, you may use a 3D editor (like [Blender](https://www.blender.org/)) to add them. For more information, take a look at the [Texture Maps section of the OBJ file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file#Texture_maps).